# Configure .htaccess to process segments of the URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I would like to be able to process the following segments of a URL to an application:

```
https://example.com/app/date/category
```

Where

- `/app` is the directory on the website
- `/date` is a string value to be passed eg; `January_7`
- `/category` is a text value to be passed eg; `births`

and route it to `index.php` for processing.

Can this be accomplished using the `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this in `.htaccess`. How you want the values passed to your PHP script can determine exactly how you'd write the necessary directives in `.htaccess`.

This assumes your `.htaccess` file is located in the `/app` subdirectory and `index.php` is also located at `/app/index.php`.

One way is to use `FallbackResource` that specifies the URL that all requests that should be rewritten to that would otherwise trigger a 404. For example:

```
FallbackResource /app/index.php
```

Then, in `index.php` you would parse the required path segments from the PHP superglobal: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. Note that all URLs are routed to `index.php`, including those that don't match your pattern, so it is up to your PHP to process this accordingly.

---

Alternatively, if you want to pass the individual path segments to `index.php` in the form of GET params then you could do something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/([\w-]+)$ index.php?date=$1&category=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The first two conditions (`RewriteCond` directives) ensure the request is not for a file or directory (to avoid rewriting static resources).

- `(\w+)` captures the "date" path segment, which is later referenced in the *substitution* with the `$1` backreference. `\w` is a shorthand character class representing the characters `0-9`, `a-z`, `A-Z` and `_`.
- `([\w-]+)` captures the "category" path segment, which is later referenced in the *substitution* with the `$2` backreference. This also allows `-` (hyphen) in addition to the characters mentioned above.

Then, in your PHP code you access `$_GET['date']` and `$_GET['category']` to access your values.

In this second example, the request is only rewritten when it matches the expected URL request pattern, ie. `/app/<date>/<category>`.

Comment: Yes, `AllowOverride` is required in the server config to enable the use of `.htaccess` files. (If you have access to the server config then you don't necessarily need to use `.htaccess` - but it can be "easier" since you don't need to restart the webserver between changes and can more easily be included in version control etc.)

Comment: If `limit` is always a number then you can be more restictive with the regex. eg. `\d+` instead of `[\w-]+` to allow 1 or more digits (0-9) only.

Comment: `RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteRule ^([\w]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)$ index.php?date=$1&category=$2&limit=$3 [QSA,L] Works now with 3 segments` I'll change the last \w to \d+ -- thanks!